# spring boot: disable @Bean definition from external @Configuration class

Tags: spring-boot

I'm using a libreary that contains a `@Configuration` class which's setting this bean:

```java
@Configuration
public abstract class BaseConfig {
 
    @Bean
    public ISchedulerService schedulerService() {
        return new HapiSchedulerServiceImpl().setDefaultGroup(HAPI_DEFAULT_SCHEDULER_GROUP);
    }

    // other beans
}
```

I need to replace the `@Bean` definition by my own.

Is there anyway to disable this concreate `@Bean` definition?

I know, I'm able to disable a `@Configuration` class using for example:

```java
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = {BaseConfig.class})
```

However, it's goinf to disable all other `@Bean` definitions.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can use `@Primary` for your new configuration, but that can lead to another issues. If you can modify the `BaseConfig` then you can probably use something like

```
@Bean
@ConditionalOnMissingBean
public ISchedulerService schedulerService() {
    return new HapiSchedulerServiceImpl().setDefaultGroup(HAPI_DEFAULT_SCHEDULER_GROUP);
}
```

and then you should be safe to define your own config.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try [enable bean overriding](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.1-Release-Notes#bean-overriding)? In your `application.properties`:

```
spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding=true
```

But it is difficult to guess which bean will have priority because the bean creation order is determined by dependency relationships mostly influenced in runtime.

If you can modify `BaseConfig`, you probably should use one of the `@Condition...` annotation like the @bilak said.